# How to say “Someone offered to take our things”, in a polite setting?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, phrase, expression

I want to say, “Somebody offered to take our things”, as a polite gesture. 
(so not stealing our things, or just taking them for no reason.) There are just so many different ways to say *take* — I’m not sure which is appropriate!

Comment: Welcome to the German Language SE. Can you provide more context please? Is the taking temporary or permanent?

Answer (score 2):

> Jemand bot an, unsere Sachen an sich zu nehmen.

Wenn sich derjenige mit diesen Sachen entfernt, eher:

> Jemand bot an, unsere Sachen mitzunehmen.

Answer (score 2):

How about

> Jemand bot an, uns unsere Sachen abzunehmen.

If you want to express that the person personally takes your things (i.e. doesn’t just put them somewhere else or gives them away), you can add the reflexive pronoun **sich**:

> Jemand bot sich an, uns unsere Sachen abzunehmen.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] and visit the [help] for questions about the site. Since we don’t deal with codes, using monospace formatting (‘backticks’) is discouraged. Rather, add a `>` at the beginning of a line for blockquote formatting. (Can be nested.)